# Custom query cache key with RTK (redux toolkit query)

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

Have tried reading the [docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/queries#query-cache-keys) but nothing,is there a way to override the default RTk query cache key mechanism so i can setup my own keys like in react query ? if so how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using [serializeQueryArgs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#serializequeryargs).

But generally, cache keys in RTK Query are an implementation detail and I don't think there is a lot of good reason to fiddle with that?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to have my own cache keys, because I was querying some data in a child component, and I wanted to consume the data in a grandparent component.I was using lazy query, so I would fetch data on demand (onClick).

The problem is that every time you use a query, redux toolkit query will make a new instance. It means that you can use the same lazy query function in different components, without having them interfere with each other.

Back to my problem, the only way you could share data between two components, while using on-demand data fetching is using `mutations`, because you can actually provide your own [fixedCacheKey](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/mutations#shared-mutation-results) . It means that every mutation with the same `fixedCacheKey` will have access to the same data, with no need to calling the fetch function every time, or saving it to a separate slice (which I find of really poor taste).
Here is an example:

Grandchild component:

```
const GrandChild = () => {
const [mutationFunc, {data, isLoading, error}] = useGetDataMutation({fixedCacheKey: 'Your key'})

return(
<div>
    <button onClick={mutationFunc}>
        fetchData
    </button>
</div>
)
}
```

And the grandparent function:

```
const GrandParent = () => {
const [mutationFunc, {data, isLoading, error}] = useGetDataMutation({fixedCacheKey: 'Your key'})

return (
<div>
   {data?
     <AuthorizedComponents/> :
     <ChildComponent/>  // GrandChild component is its child
}
</div>
)
}
```

My case was an authentication process. I had to authenticate in the grandchild and render the authorized components, if the function was successful.